# An enigmatic partition of the chemical elements

Tags: mathematics, pattern, knowledge, chemistry

I have partitioned the chemical elements into two groups based on a certain
property that is shared by some of them, but not by the remaining ones.

The following elements have my enigmatic property:

> Bismuth, Chlorine, Gold, Helium, Iodine, Mendelevium, Nitrogen, Silver

The following elements do not have my enigmatic property:

> Dubnium, Erbium, Nobelium, Terbium, Ytterbium, Yttrium, Zinc, Zirconium

Which of the following elements do have this property?

> Aluminium, Fluorine, Francium, Gallium, Lutetium, Neon, Oxygen, Polonium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property is

> **having a prime atomic number.**

The first group:

> Bismuth 83
>  Chlorine 17
>  Gold 79
>  Helium 2
>  Iodine 53
>  Mendelevium 101
>  Nitrogen 7
>  Silver 47
>  **All of these atomic numbers are prime.**

The second group:

> Dubnium 105 (divisible by 5)
>  Erbium 68 (divisible by 2)
>  Nobelium 102 (divisible by 2)
>  Terbium 65 (divisible by 5)
>  Ytterbium 70 (divisible by 5)
>  Yttrium 39 (divisible by 3)
>  Zinc 30 (divisible by 5)
>  Zirconium 40 (divisible by 5)
>  **None of these atomic numbers are prime.**

Therefore, of the final group:

> Aluminum 13 (prime)
>  Fluorine 9 (divisible by 3)
>  Francium 87 (divisible by 3)
>  Gallium 31 (prime)
>  Lutetium 71 (prime)
>  Neon 10 (divisible by 5)
>  Oxygen 8 (divisible by 2)
>  Polonium 84 (divisible by 2)
>  **Aluminum, Gallium, and Lutetium have the property.**